# ¿Cómo puedo llamar a un método de otra clase?

Tags: java

Quiero hacer que si presione la opción 1 del menú, salga un método que estoy haciendo en otra clase.

```java
package Examenlogin;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Agregar {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        int opcion = 0;
        String usuario, correo, clave;
        String nombre, electronico, contra;
                
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("1. Inicia sesión");
        System.out.println("2. Registrarse");
        System.out.println("3. SALIR");     
            
        System.out.println("Elige una opción");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        String m = sc.nextLine();
 
        switch (opcion) {
            case 1:              
                break;      
            case 2:      
                break;              
            case 3:                
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

y la clase que quiero poner es esta:

```java
package Examenlogin;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Login {
    public void primera(){  
        int opcionn;
        
        opcionn = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(""
        + "\n1. agregar\n"
        + "\n2. modificar\n"
        + "\n3. eliminar\n"
        ));
      
        switch(opcionn){
            case 1:            
                break;
            case 2:
                
                break;
                
            case 3:
                
                break;
            
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida al sitio. ¿Podrías editar la pregunta y pegar el código completo en modo texto en lugar de imagen? Incluye el código de la otra clase también. Al final lo que tendrás que hacer seguramente es crear un nuevo objeto de la clase en algún momento y llamar a su método. Por ejemplo `Opcion1 opcion1 = new Opcion1(); opcion1.metodo();` pero no se puede saber exactamente lo que se necesita hasta que se vea la otra clase y el método que hay que llamar.

Comment: ya mi amigo, muchas gracias por la correccion

Answer (score 1):

Una solucion seria creando el metodo publico y darle parametros para que haga con los parametros lo que necesites por ejemplo:

```
public class Suma{

    public int sumar_dos_numeros(int numero_1, int numero_2){

        return numero_1 + numero_2;
    }
}
```

Cuando estes en la clase donde lo necesitas llamar puedes crear un objeto de la segunda clase que tiene el metodo publico algo como:

```
//Crear un objeto del tipo de la clase la cual contiene el metodo publico
Suma nombre_objeto = new Suma();
```

y asi puede utilizar el metodo:

```
nombre_objeto.sumar_dos_numeros(5, 7);
```

Espero te sea util

Comment: una pregunta, puedo poner un submenu en un menu?

Comment: Es que no entiendo que estas intentando hacer, debes de ser mas clara la pregunta

Answer (score 1):

Tienes 2 opciones:

O cambiar el método primera de la clase Login a estático y llamarlo desde la clase Main como Login.primera:

```
public class Login {
public static void primera(){  
    int opcionn;
    
    opcionn = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(""
    + "\n1. agregar\n"
    + "\n2. modificar\n"
    + "\n3. eliminar\n"
    ));
  
    switch(opcionn){
        case 1:            
            break;
        case 2:
            
            break;
            
        case 3:
            
            break;
        
    }        
}
```

O en su defecto, crear un objeto Login desde la clase Main de esta forma y llamar al método desde el objeto que has creado:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Login miLogin = new Login();

miLogin.primera();}
```

Espero que sirva, aunque creo que ya llego tarde, igual le sirve a alguien en el futuro ;)

Salu2.